# Ansible hostname resolution with ipaddr filter returns False?

Tags: ansible, resolution, filter

I'm trying to figure this out. How does the Ansible IP Addr filter work, this always seems to return False

```
$ ansible -m debug -a 'msg={{"www.google.com"|ipv4}}' 10.1.38.15
10.1.38.15 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ipv4 filter is not a name resolution filter.  It simply tests if the passed string is a valid IPv4 address.

If you want to resolve a DNS address  you probably should be using the lookup plugin 'dig'.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dig.html

Example

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug \
  -a 'msg={{lookup("dig","www.google.com/a",wantlist=true)|first}}'

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "172.217.14.196"
}
```